# Mysql returning multiple comma separated records

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to return a list of discussions and their attached queues (ids and names).

So far I have the following:

```
SELECT a.id as discussion_id,c.queue_id,e.queue_name
FROM support_discussions AS a

JOIN (
 SELECT b.queue_id,b.discussion_id
 FROM support_queues_discussions AS b
) AS c ON a.id=c.discussion_id

JOIN (
 SELECT d.id,d.name AS queue_name
 FROM support_queues AS d
) AS e ON c.queue_id=e.id
```

This returns the following (as expected):

> discussion_id | queue_id | queue_name
>
> 1  | 1 | Queue name A
>
> 1  | 2 | Queue name B

What I'd really like to do is to get it to return each discussion as one line, along with separate columns for the queue id and the queue name:

> discussion_id | queue_id | queue_name
>
> 1  | 1,2 | Queue name A,Queue name B

Any thoughts on how this can be done in an efficient manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is GROUP_CONCAT function in mysql which does exactly what you want

did you think about what will happen if queue name contains comma character? maybe you should rethink your solution because what you described sounds way to dodgy

Comment: I know for a fact there won't be any commas in the queue name as I have a list of them all in front of me ;) I'd appreciate your thoughts on how it'd be best to do this then.. I didn't like the thought of doing individual queries for each discussion record, so was aiming to compress it all down into one query.

Comment: problem is that order of values produced by GROUP_CONCAT is not deterministic. in other words - you can't assume that first value in queue_id will correspond to first value in queue_name. you could try loading data in bulks by doing something like select discussion_id, queue_id from ... join ... where discussion_id in (list of ids) - that should bring number of queries down quite a bit

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

Comment: I've had a go with GROUP_CONCAT, but I think I've hit a problem. If it returns a comma separated list in the 1st join the 2nd join's on statement won't work (c.queue_id=e.id). I hope that makes sense!!